# Excel or VBA : Formula for Compare from Multiple Column and Multiple Sheets Then Add The Data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need some help because i'm stuck. 
I have a data (in one column) that need to be compare in the multiple columns in multiple sheets and then the value should be add on the column.

> Here's my case...

```
Data in sheet "TOTAL"
Col. A
  1
  2
  3
```

```
Sheet "AREA_A"
Col. "A"    Col. C     Col. E
  1           1          1
  2           2          2
  3           3          4
```

```
Sheet "AREA_B"
Col. "A"    Col. C     Col. E
  1           1          6
  5           7          2
  3           3          4
```

```
Sheet "AREA_C"
Col. "A"    Col. C     Col. E
  1           1          1
  5           6          2
  3           3          4
```

```
Sheet "AREA_D"
Col. "A"    Col. C     Col. E
  8           1          1
  2           9          2
  3           10         4
```

I need number 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 to be add on the column A in sheets "TOTAL".
I try using vlookup but vlookup can not doing in the multiple columns in multiple sheets.
If any formula that can fix my case, it will be good. But, using VBA is okay too.
Thank you...

Comment: You should better explain logic that you use and what should be desired result. Good work on sample data though :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i'm so sorry. i'm bad in english.